# C: How to detect a re-entry of a char character?

Tags: c

> I am creating a program whereby;
>   the first input e.g.  'a'   will give a "no duplicate" result,
>   and upon re-entry of 'a' it should would give me a "duplicate has found" result.

```
I am having a hard time finding the logic to this program. Help would be much appreciated. Thanks.
```

> I am working on lines 127-129 btw. https://pastebin.com/wQKH3iZE

Comment: Post code, not links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you have an array of length 256 (assuming you use single-byte chars), initialise all values to 0.  Then when a character is entered, cast it to int, look up if it has been entered before, and then set the corresponding array element to 1.

```
int entered_char[256] = {0};

...

// in the main game loop, when you receive a guess
if (entered_char[(int) guess]){
... //already guessed
} else {
... //new guess
    entered_char[(int) guess] = 1;
}
```

Note that this could be made much more memory efficient by using bit shifting to store one bit per "has this character been guessed?" but I couldn't be bothered.

Comment: Thank you for answering